# Why does blender select an adjacent face when I click on a specific face

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices, faces, select

When I click the face as indicated in the picture, I it also selects the adjacent face which I don't want.

I appreciate the help and apologies for the entry level question here, still learning.[image]

Comment: it seems you have a larger face that overlaps two smaller one (or something like this)? Try to see what you can select when in edge select mode.

Comment: yes you should delete this face and refill

Comment: I created the faces with looptools, so not sure why it would have this behavior.